# Aligning 0=0 with systeme package

Tags: alignment, systeme

How can I properly align an equation of the form 0=0 when using the systeme package? As a minimal example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,systeme}

\begin{document}
\[
\sysdelim..\systeme{x_1+2x_4=9,
x_2+x_4=11,
x_3-x_4=-5,
0=0
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sincerely I have not understood without a drawing example your assert "How can I properly align an equation of the form 0=0".

Comment: To follow up on @Sebastiano's comment: Please clarify what you mean by "properly align". Your sample code does compile. FWIW, in my opinion the visual appearance of the typeset result is exactly what I thought *ex ante* it would (and should) be.